# What is the difference between RelayState and redirect_uri?

Tags: single-sign-on, oauth

I believe RelayState is for deep links after authentication and redirect_uri is where you send a user after they are authenticated. I could be wrong through. I have not found any documentation comparing the two. Would they ever be used together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

redirect_url is the authorized endpoint into the system. It should *not* be a deep link. Services may choose not to authorize the client if the redirect_url is not authorized. The RelayState is the state of the application, which may be a deep link, a collection of data to be used (e.g. a Single Page Application may use a hash fragment), or something else. redirect_url is the only required parameter, but RelayState can be used as a deep link within the application.

Comment: are they ever used together in a flow?

Comment: @TylerZika Yes, if RelayState is used, they are always both used.

Answer (score 1):

`redirect_uri` is from oAuth and `RelayState` is from SAML. They're apples and oranges that live in different universes. You will not see them together in the same flow with the exception of extremely rare cases when a SAML flow is triggered by an oAuth flow or vice versa.

`redirect_uri`: after a user successfully authorizes an application, the Authorization Server will redirect the user back to the application with either an authorization code or access token. The destination of this redirect is taken from the value of `redirect_uri`.

`RelayState`: is used to communicate state when the message is passed to/from Identity Provider and Service Provider. The SAML spec requires `RelayState` to be an opaque value of 80 chars with no further specification as to what it means or how it should be treated. Therefore what happens on the Service Provider side after it reads `RelayState` is implementation-dependent. A popular implementation choice is to use `RelayState` for so-called deep-linking by encoding a destination URL as its value wherein the Service Provider will issue a redirect to the destination URL that came in `RelayState`. That usually violates the spec being longer than 80 chars and (if not careful) causes security issues.